# ssh login and untar file

Tags: ssh

I have two server (LOCAL) 192.168.1.1 and (REMOTE) 192.168.15.2

I want to untar a file from LOCAL (192.168.1.1) on REMOTE (192.168.15.2) via an SSH connection. What command can I use for that?

source path: `/home/user/example.tar.gz`

target path: `/mnt/untar/extracted_folder`

Answer (score 4):

On the source system (`LOCAL`):

```
ssh -e none 192.168.15.2 'tar -xzf - -C /mnt/untar/' </home/user/example.tar.gz
```

Comment: bash: /home/user/example.tar.gz: No such file or directory
i m getting this error

Comment: @AmrutNadgiri And what shall I do about it if you say the file is there but it isn't?

Answer (score 0):

### Try this

```
ssh root@host1 "cd /dir/tocopy/ && tar -cf - ." | \
ssh root@host2 "cd /dir/tocopyto/ && tar -xf -"
```

#### NJOY